# Where do I get my WCF service to handle X509 certificates? C#.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

Hello all I've knocked up a WCFservice and a client. I also have a class to validated X509 certificates.

Here is a snippet of the Web.config file of the service:

```
<behavior name="HelloWorldWFC2.Service1Behavior">
 <serviceCredentials>
  <serviceCertificate findValue="Service"
       x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
       storeLocation="CurrentUser"
       storeName="My" />

  <clientCertificate>
   <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"
       customCertificateValidatorType="type" />
  </clientCertificate>
 </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
```

But I don't know where to handle the receiving of certificates? I assume there is something I specficially have to overwrite because apparently not handling them allows anything to connect etc. etc.

Any help most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

That customCertificateValidatorType attribute allows you to specify the full name of a class that derives from X509CertificateValidator and decides if it wants to accept the certificate or not. There's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx) of this in the WCF documentation.

Notice that if you don't want/need that, then you can set certificateValidationMode to one of the [other possible values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificatevalidationmode.aspx) to have the certificate be checked automatically against a certificate store.